# How to prevent double submitting forms in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, post, express, submit

I have come across the problem that people on my website can double-submit a form. This isn't an issue from the database side, as the records are saved by server-side validation. However, it's important I invalidate any additional requests so that users don't get double charged (as the charge occurs prior to the account being made). I would prefer to drop the request entirely as opposed to redirecting because it will really ruin the UX, whereas dropping the request will just make the process "appear" longer which is a better compromise.

To clear things up, I am also using the post-redirect-get pattern, but it does not solve this problem, which is actually the most critical problem because it is the most common. Implementing a client-side solution will be done for cleanliness of the UI, but I cannot trust the user to not disable javascript or somehow tamper with it.

I have a middleware solution using the library `csurf` that doesn't quite work.

```
var protect_route = function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.session.unique_requests){
    req.session.unique_requests = [];
  }

  var found = _.find(req.session.unique_requests, function(token){
    return token === req.body._csrf;
  });

  if(!found){
   req.session.unique_requests.push(req.body._csrf);
   next();
  } else {
   next('route'); //drop the post, and skip anything else.
  }
};

var unlock_route = function(req, res, next){
  req.session.unique_requests = _.without(req.session.unique_requests, req.body._csrf);
};
```

I attach it to my routes like so:

```
router.post('/create', protect_route, function(req, res){
   // If it makes it in here, the route is protected and the 
   // request wasn't dropped.
});

router.get('/review', unlock_route, function(req, res){
   // The form will once again be able to be submitted.
});
```

Unfortunately, even though the middleware gets called, if I mash the create button it will fire off a ton of requests, each will attempt to push the token onto the `unique_requests`, and the result is it won't block any requests for a few pushes until everything catches up.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** Rate-limiting the POST to /create seems like a possibility, though it doesn't seem like a *real* solution I suppose. It might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simplify it by just handling a flag with those middleware, like so:

```
var protect_route = function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.session.processing){
    req.session.processing = true; // set flag
    next(); // continue in route chain
  } else {
    res.status(400).send() // end request here with 400 status code, drop everything
  }
}

var unlock_route = function(req, res, next){
  req.session.processing = false; // unset flag
  next();
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this suffers from the same problem. The mashing of the button creates multiple requests. Node doesn't handle these synchronously, so the middleware doesn't "realize" it until after the request is done. You can see this for yourself by placing console.log statements in each one of the middleware functions and then mashing the submit button until it blocks.

Comment: Right before you call next, force the session to save. Usually this is done at the end of the request. `req.session.save(function() { next() })` -- still not perfect, but if you've got long-running async stuff happening after this, should help to minimize the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
     by using a simple session counter and set it as needed  in this example of 
     adding a role name single field string unique in schema definition
     counter field name is   rolesubmitcounter
     ///////////////////////////////////////////
     router.get('/add',ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res){
     req.session.rolesubmitcounter=0;
     res.render('roles/role_add',{
     title:"add role",
     nrole: {roleName:""}
     });
    });
    // Add Submit POST Route
     router.post('/add', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
     if (req.session.rolesubmitcounter ===0){
     var tt1 =req.body.roleName.toString().trim();
    if(tt1==="".trim()){
    req.session.rolesubmitcounter=0;
       req.flash('danger','Role not..added.....may be empty fields......');
        res.render('roles/role_add', {
        title:'Add role',
        nrole: {roleName:req.body.roleName}
       });
      }
      else{
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    req.session.rolesubmitcounter = 1;
   let nrole = new Role();
   nrole.roleName = req.body.roleName.toLowerCase().trim();
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   nrole.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      req.session.rolesubmitcounter=0;
       req.flash('danger','Role not..added.....may be duplicate key..');
       res.render('roles/role_add',{
       nrole: nrole
        });
      } else {
       req.flash('success','Role Added');
       res.redirect('/roles/roleindex');
       }
    });
    }
    }else{
     req.flash('danger','double submission Detected.....click once slowly');
     res.redirect('/roles/roleindex');
    }

   });
```

Comment: rolesubmitcounter is initialized  in  router.get  to value 0 , in subsequent submit   its value   is setted  also to  value 0  in case of invalid  data or  save error like dup key value before rendering input form again from post ,   if  save is success  the value  is  1  which detects  the  double success  submission

Comment: Edit your answer